# Qt Layout Contents Auto-Fit

Tags: qt

How can we set Qt Layout contents' auto-fit/auto-resize options?
Even when I try to use setSizePolicy method with QSizePolicy::Expanding argument, it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: check this if it can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337589/qlistwidget-adjust-size-to-content/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your setSizePolicy applied on the objects which are added to layout?