# Init QListWidget to show its all content (with no scroll bars)

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I was playing with the [Config Dialog Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dialogs-configdialog.html), all was fine. Then I changed something in the right part of the dialog.
Then I found the `contentsWidget` (QListWidget) in the left part of the dialog became smaller and showed the scroll bars (both Horizontal and Vertical).

I want the QListWidget to show all its content so that no scroll bars are needed.
All items are added at the beginning and fixed. No dynamic.
I guess there is a simply method to let the QListWidget expand to show all its content at the beginning.

Could anyone help me and tell me the magic word?

Here is the code:

```
contentsWidget = new QListWidget;
contentsWidget->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
contentsWidget->setIconSize(QSize(96, 84));
contentsWidget->setMovement(QListView::Static);
contentsWidget->setMaximumWidth(128);
contentsWidget->setSpacing(12);
//contentsWidget->setMinimumWidth(contentsWidget->sizeHintForColumn(0));
//contentsWidget->setMaximumWidth(contentsWidget->sizeHintForColumn(0));
//contentsWidget->adjustSize();
//qDebug()<<contentsWidget->sizeHintForColumn(0);
createIcons();
contentsWidget->setCurrentRow(0);

QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
horizontalLayout->addWidget(contentsWidget);
horizontalLayout->addWidget(pagesWidget, 1);
```

I tried `contentsWidget->sizeHintForColumn(0)`, but it didn't work. It was 0. I tried some other methods but nothing worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QListWidget adjust size to content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337589/qlistwidget-adjust-size-to-content)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try:

```
contentsWidget->setMinimumWidth(128);
```

This will ensure that no matters what, the size of `contentsWidget` will always be at least 128, hence large enough to contains the icons.